# Patent Violation due to same principal

Tags: electricity-charging

In reference to the patent: [US20140001760](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140001760)

Hi Does this patent [US20120286513 A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20120286513A1/en) already violate the above patent. This clearly the same thing in principal. Please let me know as I would like to file a patent in a different way powered via wind

Answer (score 1):

The documents you've identified are patent applications, not yet patents. Applications may or may not get to be patents depending on the examination process which includes searching for prior art. As you have pointed out US20120286513 A1 certainly looks like prior art to US20140001760 A1. I looked in to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site and US20120286513 A1 has been abandoned after receiving a final rejection. Final rejections aren't necessarily final, but it looks like the applicant decided to give up in the face of the examiner's objections. In the case of S20140001760 A1, the status is also abandoned. It looks like it's applicant gave up after receiving a non-final rejection.

So the bottom line is neither of these applications are at all likely to become patents. They are, however still prior art to any invention you might try to patent. Since they both received rejections, it would be an excellent idea for you to review the rejection documents for the two applications. The process is to go to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site, get past the CAPTCHA, select "Document Number" and then enter just the number between the US and A1. For example, "20120286513" or "20140001760". Click on the "Image File Wrapper" tab and you will find links to the documents containing the rejections and other communications between the applicants and the patent office.